# Adding a class or ID to this image / what does this line mean?

Tags: javascript

I have a large JavaScript file which I can't really understand.

For example, this line:

> [
>                 ["images/edge_up-sheet0.png", 331274, 0, 0, 1920, 1160, 1, 0.5, 0,[],[],0]          ]

What do all the numbers mean?

Also, is it possible to add a class or id to that image?
Thanks

This is part of the function as the JS file is huge:

```
cr.getProjectModel = function() { return [
    null,
    "preloader",
    [
    [
        cr.plugins_.AJAX,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false
    ],
[
        "t3",
        cr.plugins_.Sprite,
        false,
        [5455186370050571],
        0,
        0,
        null,
        [
            [
            "Default",
            5,
            false,
            1,
            0,
            false,
            255122223176628,
            [
                ["images/edge_up-sheet0.png", 331274, 0, 0, 1920, 1160, 1, 0.5, 0,[],[],0]
            ]
            ]
        ],
```

Comment: This is just a JS data structure – without knowing by what code is processed no one can tell you what the individual values “mean”.

Comment: This isn't an image - it's an array inside an array. The numbers are whatever you want them to be (how are we supposed to know why an array has a bunch of numbers?). The "image" is just a string.

Comment: This is basically an array containing an array of meta data relating to an image, you need to find the function which uses this array to find out what happens with each part of the array, the `"images/edge......"` bit is obviously the `src`, the `1920` and `1160` is probably height and width but i'd only be guessing the rest.

Comment: @MarkWalters *Perhaps* `331274` is the decimal value of `0x050E0A` and is supposed to be the background colour? `1` *could* be the opacity? This is all just guessing.

Comment: @h2ooooooo quite possibly, I think the OP needs to show the function which makes use of this array of metadata for us to be able to help in any way at all.

Comment: I've added some of the function, but the file is huge and I can't really paste all of it.

Comment: Well that isn't the function that makes use of the data you initially showed us, it is just more of the data structure. Although this does tell us that you are making use of a jQuery plugin by the looks of it. You need to find out what plugin uses this code and then from there find their website and read their docs on how to use it.